# Open an archive file which is in another archive file using Java

Tags: java, zip, php-ziparchive

I have a file named "file.ear". This file contains several files, including a "war" file, named "file.war" (which is also an archive). I intend to open a text file which is in "file.war". In this moment, my question is which is the best way to create a ZipFile object from this "file.war"

I created a ZipFile object from "file.ear" and iterated the entries. When the entry is "file.war" I tried to create another ZipFile

```
ZipFile earFile = new ZipFile("file.ear");
Enumeration(? extends ZipEntry) earEntries = earFile.entries();

while (earEntries.hasMoreElements()) {
    ZipEntry earEntry = earEntries.nextElement();
    if (earEntry.toString().equals("file.war")) {
        // in this line I want to get a ZipFile from the file "file.war"
        ZipFile warFile = new ZipFile(earEntry.toString());
    }
}
```

I expect to get a ZipFile instance from "file.war" and the line marked throws a FileNotFoundException.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ZipFile` is only for ... files. A `ZipEntry` is only in memory, not on the harddrive.

You're better off using `ZipInputStream` :

1. you wrap your `FileInputStream` into a `ZipInputStream`
2. you get a hold onto the .war entry's `InputStream`
3. you wrap the .war in turn `InputStream`into a `ZipInputStream`
4. you can get a hold on the text file entry, read its `InputStream`
5. do whatever you want with the text `InputStream`!

```java
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipInputStream;

public class Snippet {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        InputStream w = getInputStreamForEntry(new FileInputStream("file.ear"), "file.war");
        InputStream t = getInputStreamForEntry(w, "prova.txt");

        try (Scanner s = new Scanner(t);) {
            s.useDelimiter("\\Z+");
            if (s.hasNext()) {
                System.out.println(s.next());
            }
        }

    }

    protected static InputStream getInputStreamForEntry(InputStream in, String entry)
            throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(in);

        ZipEntry zipEntry = zis.getNextEntry();

        while (zipEntry != null) {
            if (zipEntry.toString().equals(entry)) {
                // in this line I want to get a ZipFile from the file "file.war"
                return zis;
            }
            zipEntry = zis.getNextEntry();
        }
        throw new IllegalStateException("No entry '" + entry + "' found in zip");
    }

}
```

HTH!

Comment: The file is in a folder structure inside the "war" archive. The InputStream "t" was called as " t = getInputStreamFactory(w, "FolderName/SubfolderName/prova.txt"); " . It works fine.

Comment: Great news @CatalinVladu - you may want to accept the solution then - to help others with similar problem...